# Sonarqube 4.5.1 Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner' in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I am running Sonarqube 4.5.1 on my Mac. I could view the welcome page at localhost:9000.
I created a very simple Java application project with Gradle in Eclipse, and wrote some classes and unit tests  it. However, it's reporting a JDK error when I run the command `gradle sonarRunner`.

OS X Yosemite 10.10.1
JDK: 1.7.0_72
Sonarqube: 4.5.1 
Gradle: 2.2.1

Exception info:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
**Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.sonar.runner.tasks.SonarRunner.run(SonarRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 44 more
```

I had tried Sonarqube 4.3.3 and 4.1.2 and reinstall jkd1.7.0_71. Could someone give me some pointers?

build.gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
    jacoco {
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}

sonarRunner {
    toolVersion = "2.4"
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "gradledemo sonar report"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "gradledemo"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"

        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
        property "sonar.sources", "src"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

I got below info when I append -i parameter to command 'gradle sonarRunner'.

```html
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: File [relative=src/test/java/org/gradle/PersonTest.java, abs=/Users/qiaorongrong/Documents/workspace/gradleapp002/src/test/java/org/gradle/PersonTest.java] can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
:sonarRunner FAILED
:sonarRunner (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 4.514 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What is 'File be index twice'? Maybe I need modify some configure?

Comment: an you show us build.gradle

Comment: please run your build with "-i" and "--stacktrace". We need to understand the root cause of the failing sonarRunner task to be able to help you.

Comment: is it sonarRunner or sonarRunnerQube task? I saw somewhere that with newer version of Gradle and SonarQube/runner, in Gradle the plugin name has changed and also the task name as well. For ex: with later Gradle version, you can't use:    apply plugin: 'sonar-runner' but you can try: apply plugin: 'sonarqube-runner' and    // The following is need if you are using SonarQube 4.5 and sonar-runner 2.4. Plugin needs to changed to apply plugin: 'sonarqube-runner' and task should be sonarQubeRunner
   //
   sonarRunner {
    toolVersion = '2.4'
   }

Comment: I think this information is outdated again. The plugin is now called sonarqube and the task as well. See for current information:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it finally. The thing is:

1. modify gradle-wrapper.properties to make gradle wrapper use gradle 2.2.1(latest now) 
   `distributionUrl=http\://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip`
2. sonarRunner plugin version error. configure it in build.gradle:

```html
sonarRunner {
        toolVersion = '2.4'
    }
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = '0.7.2.201409121644'
    }
```

3. after configure above. the error info is 'DB connection error' - cannot build connection with sonar      default DB. In fact, I use mysql to sonar. so add below configure in build.gradle:

```html
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", “sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", “sonar"
    }
   }
```

Why did I spent so long days to fix it? - I am lack of knowledge of Gradle, Gradlew and our multiple project. 
So it should be easy if I am very familiar with Gradle how to work.

reference docs:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_plugin.html

Finally, thanks you read and answer my questions. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

With the versions of Gradle and Sonar that you are using, shouldn't you be using as there are API level changes since they recently released new versions.

```
   //apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
   apply plugin: 'sonarqube-runner'
```

and

Gradle task: "**sonarQubeRunner**" instead of "sonarRunner"

FYI:

```
// The following is required if you are using SonarQube 4.5 and sonar-runner 2.4. Plugin needs to changed to apply plugin: 'sonarqube-runner' and task should be sonarQubeRunner
   //
   sonarRunner {
    toolVersion = '2.4'
   }
```

Comment: `Plugin [id: 'sonarqube-runner'] was not found in any of the following sources:`