# Azure DevOps pipeline for a Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a CI pipeline for a Kotlin project developed on Android Studio. Using Azure DevOps pipelines.

I'm having an issue finding a Kotlin plugin or Tasks for the pipeline as we can see in the picture.

Anyone have an idea about how can we implement this type of pipeline? I didn't find anything on the internet and Microsoft have no documentation.

[image]

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598036/sonarqube-4-5-1-execution-failed-for-task-sonarrunner-in-gradle) of modifying gradle-wrapper.properties to fix the `Unable to execute Sonar` error.  Here is an example to [Integrating and Understanding SonarQube in Android](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/). Hope it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with Kotlin or Java. The issue was with the `SDK` being used on the Hosting Agent.
The solution was the following steps:

1. Upload a `SDK` to Azure Blob Storage
2. Use the `Use Java` Task in order to install the specified `SDK`

Run the Android Pipeline with Sonarqube tasks, build was successfully run and SonarQube Code Review was successfully executed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the answer you are looking for is the Gradle task. Here is a [blog](https://techblog.tbauctions.com/kotlin-azure-and-code-coverage/) from someone using gradle and in azure devops with their Kotlin code. But I am sure there are more details around how to set up gradle task for kotlin build.

Comment: I've seen it already, but I don't want this `JaCoCo` in my gradle. Anyway I did manage to build a CI pipeline for my kotlin project. The problem now is that my pipeline is unable to execute the sonarQube task from my gradle file

Comment: There should be a "Run SonarQube or SonarCloud Analysis" option under Code Analysis in the GRadle task. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I've checked the `Run SonarQube or SonarCloud Analysis` checkbox. But the task is failing with: `Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
> Unable to execute SonarQube` You have any idea about this error?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish if your main question about build task was answered I would love getting my first accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, but your comment is not the answer for the question